# What will be the output when class B2 is run?

Tags: java

```
public class P23 {
    P23() {
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B2 extends P23 {
    int i = 0; // Math.round(3.5f);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("inside main");
        P23 a = new B2();
        a.print();
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Doesn't print anything!
What am i missing?
Please help me understand how to debug this one.

Comment: *Doesn't print anything!* I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I get the output: `inside main \n 0 \n 0`. I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 under Windows 7.

Comment: inside main
0
0
After Eran's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both of those classes are in the same source file, you should make the class with the main method the public class (i.e. change `class B2` to `public class B2` and change `public class P23` to `class P23`). If they are not in the same source file, you should still make `B2` public.

After the fix, the output of the following lines would be:

```
System.out.println("inside main"); // prints 'inside main'
P23 a = new B2(); // prints "0" since the constructor of B2 calls the constructor of P23 
                  // which executes B2's print()
a.print(); // prints "0" since B2's print() is executed
```

In both calls to `print`, the `print` method of the sub-class B2 is called, since the runtime type of `a` is `B2`.

Therefore the output is

```
inside main
0
0
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran, that answered lots of my questions!

Comment: This is no answer. In fact, the (original) program shows some output. This should be a comment.

Comment: @Turing85 Edited. I originally answered why there's no output. Now I added an explanation of the output.

Comment: In short print in B2 overrides print in P23 but since a public class is required to have a main class(which wasn't present in original code), the code in B2 never was reachable.
It(ori. code) wont run from command line, i guess.

Comment: @SubhamDalmia A public class doesn't require a main method, but if you want to execute the main method of some ClassX (by running, for example, `java ClassX` from the command line), ClassX must be public.

Comment: @Eran this is not quite true. If you compile the above example, you will finde two classes within the `bin`-folder: `P23.class` and `B2.class`. You can without problems execute `java B2`, even though `B2` is not declared as `public`. This even works, if you use packages.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class P23
{
   P23() {  print();   }
   void print() { System.out.println("A"); }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    System.out.println("inside main");
      P23 a = new B2();
      a.print();
   }

}
class B2 extends P23
{
   int i = 0;  //Math.round(3.5f);
   void print() 
   { 
      System.out.println(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think above is the code that should work with original piece of code.